# Hindi Text not working properly in ImageMagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick tool for creating some images with hindi Text but it's not working properly.

Fonts: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Devanagari

I have tried with below mentioned command.

```
convert sample.jpg -fill red -pointsize 40 -font NotoSansDevanagari.ttf -annotate +100+100 "आपका हिन्दी टेक्स्ट" output_image.jpg
```

### **Wrong Output**

[image]

### **Expected Output:**

[image]

What I missed in the command to get the expected output?

Comment: Can you explain please, for those of us who don't speak Hindi, what the problem is? Those two look pretty similar to me.

Comment: You cannot just type high-ASCII characters (unless you have a compatible unicode keyboard), only low-ASCII. To get high-ASCII text, you must use a UTF-8 compatible text editor and put the text into a file. Then reference the file as @file.txt in your command.  See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode